# Auto Boxing of primitives

Tags: objective-c

I can't seem to figure out how to get Objective-c to auto box my primitives.

I assumed that i would be able to do the following

```
float foo = 12.5f;
NSNumber* bar;

bar = foo;
```

However i find that i have used to the more verbose method of

```
float foo = 12.5f;
NSNumber* bar;

bar = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:foo];
```

Am i doing it wrong or is this as good as it gets?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately, Objective-C does not do auto-boxing or unboxing of primitive types to `NSNumber`. When put that way, it may be clear why: Objective-C has no concept of `NSNumber`, a class in the Cocoa Foundation framework. As a small superset of C, Objective-C doesn't have a "native" numeric object type--just the native C types.

**Edit Aug 2012**
As of Xcode 4.4 (and LLVM 4.0), you can now use some syntactic sugar to wrap numbers. Following your example, these "boxed expressions" now work:

```
float foo = 12.5f;
NSNumber* bar;

bar = @(foo);
bar = @12.5f;
```

Comment: I might say "inconveniently" rather than "unfortunately". Languages with auto-(un)boxing are not free of problems — in fact, many of them are hard to spot and can cause strange issues. For example, Effective Java and Java Puzzlers devote quite a few pages to clearing up confusion about how numbers act unexpectedly in various situations. It would be quite convenient to have auto-boxing, but adding it to the language itself (as you point out) would be non-trivial, and likely fraught with hidden perils.

Comment: @Quinn Absolutely. I was really trying to make the point that Objective-C couldn't easily do autoboxing, not trying to make a judgement about the situation. Any of us that have "enjoyed" Java's autoboxing knows it's not a free lunch. I've heard C#'s is better, but don't have personal experience with which to judge.

Comment: Who comes back 2 years later to adjust their answer? Amazing. I was looking for the new syntax, thanks! So there's no automatic unboxing, of course, right?

Answer (score 12):

Clang 3.1 and Apple LLVM 4.0 (included in Xcode 4.4) support a new boxing feature: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#objc_boxed_expressions

You're now able to write:

```
NSNumber *bar = @(foo);
```

as well as:

```
NSNumber *bar = @12.5F;
```

So it just got a little better. :)

Answer (score -1):

Auto unboxing is possible in Objective c...

Please read the following code

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,assign)int intval;
@end
```

///Now we are going to instantiate class1 in class2 and we are gonna assign the instance variable a value through reflection

```
@implementation Class2

-(void)TestClass1
{
  Class1 *clsObj=[[Class1 alloc]init];

  [clsObj setValue:@"3" forKey:@"intval"];

  NSLog(@"%d",clsObj.intval);

}

@end
```

If u run the above code you will get value 3...There is no error

```
[clsObj setValue:@"3" forKey:@"intval"];
```

The intVal is given string value 3 and it's auto unboxed to assign as int type to the instance variable intVal

Comment: I don't see how that's unboxing. I thought unboxing would mean conversion from an NSNumber to a primitive type.