# Is there a shorthand way to get a float from an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, boxing

I'm a beginner with iPhone dev in Objective C and one thing I find I'm doing quite a lot is getting floats (and ints) in and out of various NSArrays

```
float myFloatValue = [(NSNumber *)[myArray objectAtIndex:integerSelector] floatValue];
```

I understand that I need to do this boxing because a float (or int) isn't a pointer and the NSArray accepts only pointers.

I'm just wondering if there a little bit of syntactic sugar to shorten this line of code - mostly because when I have a couple of arrays and I'm looping over them to do some processing I find that the lines start getting massive and I have to break out the lines that extract the number form the array just to make the code readable - then I have a lot of gumph lines that tend to make the logic harder to follow.

In a language like C# I would write something like

```
float myResult = myArray[i] + someOtherArray[i+1];
```

(ok - that's probably a pretty dumb line of code - but syntactically it's quite clean, I guess because .net is doing the boxing implicitly where I can't see it)

in objective C I find myself writing:

```
float myFloatValue = [(NSNumber *)[myArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
float myOtherFloatValue = [(NSNumber *)[someOtherArray objectAtIndex:i+1] floatValue];

float myResult = myFloatValue + myOtherFloatValue;
```

I'm just wondering if I'm missing a trick here by typing it all out longhand. Should I be using an alternative to NSArray? Is there a shortcut for the boxing/unboxing?

Or I guess, should I just get used to it and stop whinging  ;)

Comment: No, Objective-C sucks. But you can use a C array if you're just storing floats. The problem with C arrays is dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Well, at the very least, why are you casting at all? This isn't C++. You can send whatever message you want to an `id` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a category:

```
@class NSArray (FloatHelper)

- (float) floatAtIndex:(NSUInteger)i;

@end

@implementation NSArray (FloatHelper)

 - (float) floatAtIndex:(NSUInteger)i {
   return [[self objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
 }

@end
```

(Untested and has no error handling, which, obviously, is not a good idea.)

Then it could be used as follows:

```
float a = [array floatAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: @Stephen: I'm not sure sure what's going on in the code you posted here - for example, where does myArray come from in this case? Also, just basic things like - where to put these declarations. I'm a beginner with objective C and haven't got enough context here, I don't suppose you have a link to a tutorial or documentation that will help me understand your answer a bit better?

Comment: Sorry, `myarray` was a cut and paste error. It should be self. See here for the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any shorthand for that, by the way

```
float myFloatValue = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
```

is legal.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Objective-C doesn't support Auto-Boxing.

For more info please visit to link -[Aotoboxing in objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477163/auto-boxing-of-primitives)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a category, a function or a macro to do this with less verbose code.

But if you are doing this in a loop that consumes significant CPU time (as determined by profiling with Instruments), you should consider using a C array instead, which can be accessed using far less CPU cycles, thus conserving the users battery life.  If you are touching the same elements multiple times, it might even be an optimization to copy all these floats from an NSArray to a plain C array of floats before doing your computation loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you **create a macro**,

```
#define _floatValue(array, index) [(NSNumber *)[array objectAtIndex:index] floatValue]
```

**use it**,

```
float myFloatValue = _floatValue(myArray, i);
float myOtherFloatValue = _floatValue(someOtherArray, i+1);
float myResult = myFloatValue + myOtherFloatValue;
```

and just **stop bothering** yourself?

Comment: Who is that funny guy down voted my answer! Why the down vote? Is my answer really a harmful idea! I don't think so!