# objective c require parameter to be a constant

Tags: objective-c

So I'm new to objective C, and typed languages in general, although I am enjoying their verbosity.

I am defining a bunch of constants like this:

```
NSString const *MAP_TILES_TYPE_IDX = @"idx";
NSString const *MAP_TILES_TYPE_MLS = @"mls";
NSString const *MAP_TILES_TYPE_PROPERTY = @"mu";
NSString const *MAP_TILES_TYPE_SERVICES = @"sr";
```

and I have a method that should only accept one of these strings:

```
-(void) addTileLayer:(NSString *)type {
...
}
```

Can anybody give me a suggestion to better enforce the fact that I want the parameter `type` to be one of my defined constants?

I'm open to any suggestion.

Comment: Have you thought about using an `enum`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace `NSString` with an `enum`, like this:

```
typedef enum {
    MAP_TILES_TYPE_IDX,
    MAP_TILES_TYPE_MLS,
    MAP_TILES_TYPE_PROPERTY,
    MAP_TILES_TYPE_SERVICES
} MapTilesType;
...
-(void) addTileLayer:(MapTilesType)type {
    ...
}
```

If you need an `NSString` for these constants, define an `NSArray` that maps `enum` values to strings, like this:

```
NSArray *tileTypeToTypeName = @[@"idx", @"mls", @"mu", @"sr"];
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `typedef enum { ... } MapTilesType` to ensure `addTileLayer` isn't called with an `int`?

Comment: @trojanfoe Absolutely! Thanks for the note!

Comment: It is absolutely necessary they be mapped to strings - I thought about doing it this exact way, but while I can define the enum at compile time, I can't map the values to the strings at compile time and then I would need to instantiate the object in order to define the array values and, thus, map the enum values - wouldn't I? I wanted to be able to map a constant to it's value without having to instantiate an object, although I understand this might not be possible.

Comment: @Adam: To convert them to strings I would actually use an `if…else if…` statement because using an `enum` type as an index works, but borders on magic. You could use an `NSDictionary` with [boxed C types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477163/auto-boxing-of-primitives) if you have a lot of different values.

Comment: @Adam Instantiating the `NSArray` object is necessary under this scheme, but you do not have to instantiate it more than once. You can make it a `static` variable in the translation unit that uses `tileTypeToTypeName` array, or make it an ivar in the class, and instantiate inside the `viewDidLoad` call.

Answer (score 3):

If you require a method to accept only certain strings, why not make it take an enum instead of NSString as an argument and internally translate the enum to a string that you need?

This way users of the method would be limited to enum values only. Plus you can hide the actual strings from them (not always needed, but looks cleaner).